# How to split a string with preceding Zeros using regular expression?

Tags: java, regex, split

How can I split a string `A000101` as `A000 and 101` ,   `000101 as   000 and 101` using the same regular expression.

I tried with something like this
`"A000101".split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)&(?!=0)")`
but output is `A  and 000101`

edit :

Can I get `A0000` and `0` from `A00000` using the same logic ?

Comment: Is `split` mandatory? Why not use a `Matcher` with capturing groups? `"([^1-9]*)([1-9]\\d*)"`

Comment: I need to generate a series between two strings. My idea is to split up and increment the integer part

Comment: Use `split` when you face a simple delimiter (comma, semicolon etc).

Comment: Java allows finite repitition in lookbehind, try `(?<=^[^1-9]{1,11})(?=[1-9])` where `11` to be replaced with max num of characters that could occure before split-border.

Answer (score 2):

It seems easier to me to use a `Matcher` instead of `split`:

```
String str = "A000101";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^1-9]*)([1-9]\\d*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.matches()) {
    String prec = m.group(1);
    String post = m.group(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this pattern as well:

```
([^0]*0*)(\d+)
```

Each group should give you one part of the string that you want in split.

#### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/pp9a0DNNox)